# HTC 8X Camera sound problem

Tags: camera, htc-8x

I recently bought a HTC 8X and see that camera sound setting is not appear in ringtones+sounds settings!!!
my phone career is **Telstra**, I searched in google and understand that my career policy removed that !!!!

Now, what is the solution for disable shutter sound in my phone?

Answer (score 3):

According to this forum thread, it doesn't look like it's possible to disable the 'Camera shutter' sound when using the HTC 8X on Telstra...

http://crowdsupport.telstra.com.au/t5/Windows-Phones/HTC-8x-camera-shutter-sound/td-p/175144

**Note:** If you were able to flash the phone with an unbranded firmware (ie. not Telstra) then the option to disable the 'Camera shutter' sound should re-appear.

Comment: is there any unbrand solution?

Comment: @sma6871 I've updated the answer with additional info.